# detect which directive calling a method in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

is there any way to detect which directive calling a function in the controller without passing any arguments from the directive itself.

simple example to demonstrate what i need:

**controller:**

```
 app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            // detect the directive calling the displayDirective function.
            var detectedDirective = ""; // <--
            $scope.displayDirective = function (message) {
                alert(message + detectedDirective );
            }
        }

    )
```

**directives:**

```
app.directive('directive1', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                update: "&"
            },
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.update({message: "I am"});
            }
        }})

app.directive('directive2', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                update: "&"
            },
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.update({message: "I am"});
            }
       }})
```

for [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMOOmwu0FQptLWLQlf4m?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, there is no way. Why don't you use full message such as `scope.update({message: "I am directive1"});`?

Comment: thanks :( this is a demonstration example, that is not what i am actually want to do.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?